# How to add encoding in python askopenfile

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, tkinter

I was wondering, is there any chance to add encoding right into `tkFileDialog.askopenfile` body?
Right now i use `askopenfilename` instead and then use `codecs` to encode file like this:

```
def open():
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.xml")])
    if filename == '':
        return
    with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        txt = f.read()
        delete(xml)
        xml.insert("1.0", txt)
```

What i'm asking is, how to do the same but using `askopenfile`, something like this:

```
with askopenfile(filetypes=[("Text files","*.xml")], encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Any suggestions or other approaches to do the same are strongly appreciated.

Comment: ok I stand correct I was the one confused :P (I deleted my non-applicable comments and answer :P)

Comment: You might be able to monkey-patch in a replacement function for `tkFileDialog.askopenfile` into the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just merge the `askopenfilename()` into the `with()`:

```
with codecs.open(askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.xml")]), encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Comment: any idea to use askopenfile?

Comment: I don't believe `askopenfile()` supports that type of functionality.

Comment: looks like you are the only one who responded but your approcah is the same as mine just a little bit shorter. Thanks anyway